# Why do I get NullPointerException when sending an SMS on an HTC Desire, or what is SubmitPdu?

Tags: android, sms

So I get this stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException    
   at android.telephony.SmsMessage$SubmitPdu.<init>(SmsMessage.java:132)
   at android.telephony.SmsMessage.getSubmitPdu(SmsMessage.java:551)
   at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:228)
   at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:107)
   at com.emergency.button.SMSSender.safeSendSMS(SMSSender.java:91)
   at com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity$EmergencyThread
       .sendSMS(EmergencyActivity.java:294)
   at com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity$EmergencyThread
       .sendMessages(EmergencyActivity.java:386)
   at com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity$EmergencyThread
       .run(EmergencyActivity.java:266)
```

And this is how I call sendTextMessage, I don't verify message length or phone number validity:

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

This error seems to only occur on HTC Desire or HTC Wildfire with android version 2.2 or 2.21 so I dug up the android platform source (which is actually not as easy to do as I expected) and found:
[SmsMessage.java once upon a time](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=telephony/java/android/telephony/SmsMessage.java;h=0617dada43e6119ab009cc917f11e1284ff09580;hb=5c1207be90fdf296c1b83034b7c68915e1749284) though this might not be relevant as I see some of the line numbers don't line up.
The [emergency button project](http://code.google.com/p/emergencybutton/) is open source so you can check the code out for reference. I should probably note that I can't test this myself, I don't have either phone model.

Comment: Are users claiming it is crashing (force close or something similar)? I tried the app from my Desire and it worked without a problem - both email and sms messages sent successfully. PDU stands for Protocol Data Unit by the way.

Comment: The android market reports crashes and I have a stack trace logger integrated as well. So yeah, it is crashing. Thanks for the info and testing, I wonder what exactly's happening.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might be hitting this issue with a message that is too long.  I don't know why it would only be happening for certain phones, though.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3718

Comment: I believe that was the problem. After switching from sendTextMessage to sendMultipartTextMessage the exception never came back. Google really needs to throw a more descriptive exception there.

Answer (score 7):

Replace

```
sms.sendDataMessage(destinationAddress, scAddress, destinationPort, data, sentIntent, deliveryIntent)
```

by

```
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Your message must be an ArrayList for that, use this method before calling sendSMS

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(locationMessage);
sendSMS(telNumber.getText().toString(),parts );
```

Comment: this is the answer, and it is on the Desire S

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but too long to post in a comment...

I think you may have multiple problems - no idea what this might mean to you but I had my desire hooked up to DDMS and gave it a try. The SMS and email were sent without problem (no errors on the stack trace) but this is what I got when using the BACK button from the Activity that shows progress (waiting for location, email sent, SMS sent etc).

```
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514): Activity com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.emergency.button.SMSSender$3@4628f068 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.emergency.button.SMSSender$3@4628f068 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:972)
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:755)
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:799)
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:786)
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:780)
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at com.emergency.button.SMSSender.safeSendSMS(SMSSender.java:75)
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity$EmergencyThread.sendSMS(EmergencyActivity.java:294)
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity$EmergencyThread.sendMessages(EmergencyActivity.java:386)
01-03 02:57:11.335: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity$EmergencyThread.run(EmergencyActivity.java:266)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514): Activity com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.emergency.button.SMSSender$2@462b1e88 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.emergency.button.SMSSender$2@462b1e88 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:972)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:755)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:799)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:786)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:780)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at com.emergency.button.SMSSender.safeSendSMS(SMSSender.java:50)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity$EmergencyThread.sendSMS(EmergencyActivity.java:294)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity$EmergencyThread.sendMessages(EmergencyActivity.java:386)
01-03 02:57:11.345: ERROR/ActivityThread(14514):     at com.emergency.button.EmergencyActivity$EmergencyThread.run(EmergencyActivity.java:266)
```

Comment: I guess it makes sense that I need to unregister the receivers after I'm done with them. It's going to be strange though because they'll need to unregister themselves. http://code.google.com/p/emergencybutton/source/browse/trunk/src/com/emergency/button/SMSSender.java?r=24

Answer (score 0):

You have to unregister sms sent intent reciever and sms delivered intent after use,
One thing you can do declare the intent Receivers as seperate class which extends BraodCast,
Then you can unregister the receivers.

Comment: Do you think that's what caused the java.lang.NullPointerException in getSubmitPdu?

Comment: See JohnWayner's answer, the referenced issue sums it up pretty nicely.