# SmsManager NullPointer Exception. Confused... so simple, should work

Tags: android

If I send the following.

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("2064035760", null, "Message", null, null);
```

It throws the following exception.

I have the proper permissions.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.telephony.SmsMessage$SubmitPdu. (SmsMessage.java:140)
    at android.telephony.SmsMessage.getSubmitPdu(SmsMessage.java:624)
    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:228)
    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580952/why-do-i-get-nullpointerexception-when-sending-an-sms-on-an-htc-desire-or-what-i) question. Have you tried using sendMultipartTextMessage? It seems that if the message is too long it will throw a NullPointerException (why I don't know). I realize your message only says "Message", but it is worth a try.