# Crashes when sending sms (NullPointerException) What should I do?

Tags: android, sms

I have an app that send sms to other android or non-android phones. You can select or input your contacts. But the problem is, that it keeps crashing when I get to the part where it sends SMS.

```
btnRecipient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        editTextRecipient.setText(name);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
                String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString(); 

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);                
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message)
    {      
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                      
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);               
    }   
}
```

and heres the LogCat:

```
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.getSubmitPduHead(SmsMessage.java:663)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage.getSubmitPdu(SmsMessage.java:339)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.telephony.SmsMessage.getSubmitPdu(SmsMessage.java:613)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:228)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:107)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:79)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at com.example.KAHTextApp.KAHTextApp.sendSMS(KAHTextApp.java:136)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at com.example.KAHTextApp.KAHTextApp.access$0(KAHTextApp.java:78)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at com.example.KAHTextApp.KAHTextApp$2.onClick(KAHTextApp.java:69)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-26 12:23:29.633: E/AndroidRuntime(11986):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what is the problem here? and how can to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks very similar to the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580952/why-do-i-get-nullpointerexception-when-sending-an-sms-on-an-htc-desire-or-what).

If you replace the method call `sendTextMessage` with `sendMultipartTextMessage` does it work? Can you log how long your variable message is at that point?

EDIT:

So it seems that if you try to send a single sms message that exceeds 160 characters, you get a null pointer exception. To avoid this, split the message into multiple parts. Here is some test code I wrote:

```
public void textSingle(View view) {
    sendSMS("XXXXXXXXXX", "Test", false);
}

public void textSingleLong(View view) {
    sendSMS("XXXXXXXXXX",
            "TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest",
            false);
}

public void textMulti(View view) {
    sendSMS("XXXXXXXXXX",
            "TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest",
            true);
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String message, boolean split) {
    ...

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    if (!split) {
        Log.d("SMSTest", "Sending single message: " + message);
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    } else {
        Log.d("SMSTest", "Sending '" + message + "' in multiple parts.");
        ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
        Log.d("SMSTest", parts.size() + " parts:");
        for (String string : parts) {
            Log.d("SMSTest", string);
        }
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
            sentList.add(sentPI);
            deliveredList.add(deliveredPI);
        }
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts, sentList,
                deliveredList);
    }
}
```

I hooked up buttons to each of these methods, and they work correctly for me, with a NullPointerException when I try to send a single long message. I don't really know why you get such an unhelpful message when you do that, but that seems to be how it is.

Comment: Nothing happens, what's the whole code for the sendMultipartTextMessage?

Comment: It works fine now, but the problem is the toast wont show up, so i dont know if the message is sent or not.

Comment: Try populating the whole arrays for sent and delivered intents. I updated my example to show what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Do it in **one line**:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```